# Why did Nick Nack switch sides?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, the-man-with-the-golden-gun

In the James Bond movie *The Man with the Golden Gun*, the bad guy Scaramanga has a dwarf manservant/accomplice named Nick Nack, played by Hervé Villechaize of later *Fantasy Island* fame.

[image]

Late in the movie, when Bond is hunting down Scaramanga at Scaramanga's beautiful island mansion, Nick Nack seems to be on Bond's side, wanting Scaramanga dead -- like when Nick Nack says to Bond "If you kill him, all this will be mine," and gestures to the island mansion.

But after Bond does kill Scaramanga, Nick Nack seems angry and tries to kill Bond, failing miserably and getting himself strung up on the mast of a boat as a result.

**Late in *The Man with the Golden Gun*, why did Nick Nack seem to switch from encouraging Bond to avenging Scaramanga?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nick Nack never intends to help Bond.  He just wants to lure Bond into the "funhouse", where Scaramanga is waiting to kill him.  If I remember correctly, the movie opens with an assassin hired by Nick Nack going into the funhouse where he is stalked and killed by Scaramanga as practice.  It seems to be part of Nick Nack's job.

The scene is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqCJqRhikDk).

Comment: Also, weren't large parts of the island exploding by the time James Bond and the Bond Girl were done escaping from it?

Answer (score -1):

Because Bond destroyed the island and left nothing for nick nack to inherit.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your answer to support this assertion?